# Why does the cat command only read from the first file descriptor?

Tags: cat, file-descriptors

From the console, I've created 2 empty files, and I tried to read them simultaneously.

```
$ echo -n '' | tee f1 > f2
$ cat f1 f2
$ cat <(tail -f f1) <(tail -f ./f2)
```

On the other console I've run my tests.

```
$ echo 'tee test' | tee -a f1 >> f2
$ echo 'f1 test' >> f1
$ echo 'f2 test' >> f2
$ cat f1 f2
tee test
f1 test
tee test
f2 test
```

However, `cat` on the first console only read outputs from the first `fd`.

```
$ cat <(tail -F ./f1) <(tail -F ./f2)
tee test
f1 test
```

Why? How do I then read simultaneously from two or more file descriptors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cat` processes its arguments sequentially; `tail -f f1` continues running, so `cat` keeps waiting for input on `<(tail -f f1)`, and doesn’t move on to processing `<(tail -f f2)`.

You’ll see the output from `tail -f f2` if you kill the first `tail`.

A better tool to track multiple files simultaneously is `tail` itself (at least, GNU `tail`):

```
tail -f f1 f2
```

If you don’t want to see file headers, use `-q`:

```
tail -qf f1 f2
```

Comment: That might be a more sensible suggestion than mine; I had not understood what the OP meant to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

`cat a b` doesn't read simultaneously from `a` and `b`; it opens `a`,
reads it from start to finish, closes `a`, and then goes on to do the
same with the next file it was given as an argument.

In the case where the arguments are pseudo-files that do `tail -f` and
thus do not have an "end", `cat` would only ever read from the first file.

If for some reason all you need is to open many files at once, `paste`
could be a way:

```
$ echo f1 >f1; echo f2 >f2
$ cat <(tail -F f1) <(tail -F f2)
f1
^C

$ paste <(tail -F f1) <(tail -F f2)
f1      f2
^C
```